# curl/file_get_contents/get_headers "failed to open stream"

Tags: php, curl, nginx, amazon-ec2, file-get-contents

After isolating my problem, I am testing my API with the following code:

```
    $url = 'http://example.com/api/myendpoint;
    print_r(get_headers($url));die();
```

Sometimes it does works, but sometimes it returns a 404. 
The link I access simply returns a JSON response.

This started to happen after I reboot my Amazon EC2 server.

If I do in local it seems to work better(but even there sometimes it doesn't work).

```
     Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx/1.10.1
    [2] => Content-Type: application/json
    [3] => Connection: close
    [4] => Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
    [5] => Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 14:47:36 GMT
    [6] => pragma: no-cache
    [7] => expires: -1
    [8] => X-Debug-Token: fadeb4
    [9] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
)
```

I tried to do in some online php testers. Same problem.

I thing it's a server configuration problem but I have no idea of how debug that.

Thank you for the help.

**UPDATE**

I got this data when I see the htmlentities of my request/response

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://example.com/api/myendpoint
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 163
    [request_size] => 206
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.00557
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004207
    [connect_time] => 0.004851
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.004874
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 579
    [speed_download] => 103949
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 579
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.005555
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => ::ffff:XX:XX:XX:XX
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => ::ffff:YY.YY.Y.YY
    [local_port] => 42744
)
```

The thing is that the primary ip XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is not my actual ip. It's my old ip, before changing the instance in amazon web-server.
This might be causing the problem, but how could I fix it?

Comment: If you think it's a server config issue, you should post your question on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead. SO is for questions about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what it was:

When I changed my amazon web server, in my OVH hosting I changed the ipv4 of my dns. 
But I didn't change the ipv6.

So sometimes when I tried to access the site the calls were being redirected to the right ip (the path showed in ipv4) and sometimes the old wrong one (the path indicated by the ipv6)